# How to remove id from http://localhost:8000/posts/2/edit when editing a data

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I have a view that show some data and have edit feature, but when clicked edit button, user will be redirected to http://localhost:8000/posts/2/edit, I dont want post id appear in the URL, what should I do?

```
<table class="table table-bordered">
    <tr>
        <th width="20px" class="text-center">No</th>
        <th>Title</th>
        <th>Content</th>
      
        <th width="280px" class="text-center">Action</th>
    </tr>
    @foreach ($posts as $post)
    <tr>
        <td class="text-center">{{ ++$i }}</td>
        <td>{{ $post->title }}</td>
        <td>{{ $post->content }}</td>
       

        <td class="text-center">
            <form action="{{ route('posts.destroy',$post->id) }}" method="POST">

                <a class="btn btn-info btn-sm" href="{{ route('posts.show',$post->id) }}">Show</a>

                <a class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" href="{{ route('posts.edit',$post->id) }}">Edit</a>

                @csrf
                @method('DELETE')

                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" onclick="return confirm('Delete?')">Delete</button>
            </form>
        </td>
    </tr>
    @endforeach
</table>
```

here is the controller

```
public function edit(Post $post)
    {
        return view('posts.edit', compact('post'));
    }
```

here is the route

```
   Route::get('/', function () {
        return view('welcome');
    });
        
    Route::resource('posts', App\Http\Controllers\PostController::class);
    Auth::routes();
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: What do you want to use instead? You need to provide something in order to identify which Post you want to edit.

Comment: My first question would be: why? You need something in the URL to know what object you are editing. If your Model by example has a unique slug, you can define a route with a {slug} parameter. So it is possible

Comment: I want to use plain URL like http://localhost:8000/posts/edit, i have unique id in my Post @Unflux

Comment: Because other user can acces different Post that they didnt create and edit it, is there any way to prevent it? @GertB.

Comment: @Kameam if you remove the id, Laravel will not know what post to edit. A solution would be adding a user id in the Post model, and checking in your controller if the user is allowed to edit the post, you can just create a if statement that wil throw an exeption: throw new Exception("Access denied", 403);

Comment: You can’t do that. You want to look at [authorisation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/authorization) in order to limit access to resources.

Comment: @GertB. could you please give me example how my edit controller looks like? Im kinda confuse to implement your suggestion, thanks in advance

Comment: @Kameam Do you have the user id stored in the Post model?

Comment: @GertB. yes, i have. the name is user_id

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to prevent users to edit posts that they did not create:

```
public function edit(Post $post)
    {
        if(Auth::user()->id != $post->user_id) {
           throw new \Exception("Access denied", 403); 
        }
        return view('posts.edit', compact('post'));
    }
```

you need to use the Auth class offcourse:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
```

You need to do the same for the delete function

Answer (score 0):

why you don't the id to appear in url. i can not see the reason to do that because there should be some unique key to edit the post. the only way i see is to add in the database a slug column and put it as unique. when adding a post put the title replacing space with '_' as a slug. make sure it is unique in validation. and in your edit and show code send the slug instead of the id.

```
 route('posts.edit',$post->slug)
```

don't use dependency injection in controller

```
public function edit(  $slug)
{
          $post = Post::where('slug','=',$slug)->first();
    return view('posts.edit', compact('post'));
}
```

Answer (score -2):

**hi
I think it will help you**

your route will be like this:

```
Route::resource('posts', App\Http\Controllers\PostController::class)->except([
    'edit'
]);
```

or

```
Route::resource('posts', App\Http\Controllers\PostController::class, ['only' => ['index', 'destroy', 'update' , 'create' , 'store']]);
```

or even you can write each route separately...

and write your edit route, separate :

```
Route::post('/post/edit', [App\Http\Controllers\PostController::class, "edit"])->name('post.edit');
```

delete     `@method('DELETE')`  from your blade and add this input to your blade :

```
<input type="hidden" name="post_id" value="{{$post->id}}" />
```

and change this :

```
public function edit(Post $post)
    {
        return view('posts.edit', compact('post'));
    }
```

to this :

```
public function edit(Request $request)
    {
       $post_id = $request->post_id;
       //write your code here
        return view('posts.edit', compact('post'));
    }
```

Comment: Thats a whole lot of work, and it will still be possible to edit other posts...

Comment: I got an error said The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: POST.

Comment: if i use element inspector, i can change the hidden input's value and still edit other posts. This is not a good solution.

Comment: route is post and your form should use the post method I think you should fix your form method. @Kameam

Comment: @GertB. yes you can not make it totally unchangeable on the front side if you want more security you should use form validate https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#form-request-validation

Comment: @alirezaalizade yes indeed, thats why i suggested a backend check.